# How do i render .php URL with .html extension

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

Hi i am using Codeigniter PHP framework.

Is there is any way to display `.html` extension rather than `.php` extension in *URL*?

Answer (score 2):

Set your url suffix on your config.php found here

`/application/config/config.php
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html'; //@ line 60ish`

Comment: It works for regular page request. but what about ajax request. when we made request to controller using ajax it brokes. please suggest

Comment: what is the request url for the ajax?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually tried it myself but see the section **Adding a URL Suffix** in [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) part of the user guide.

Answer (score 1):

Just add following to Apache's config and it will process .html files with PHP:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml
```

With that you can rename your .php files to .html.

Or you can use mod_rewrite to handle this on the fly

Answer (score 0):

use a .htaccess file that does a url rewrite .html to the equivalent .php

if you are using codeigniter you should even be thinking of hiding any extension altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If ur using APache. You can use URL Rewrite Rule.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score 0):

As others said, creating a .htaccess file will allow you to rewrite .php to .html. The following code should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

I am interested as to why you actually want to do this though. Codeigniter, by default, uses a segment based approach which is friendly and does away with query strings and file extensions. Using another htaccess rule, you can remove index.php from the url to make them even cleaner:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

So your urls can look like this: example.com/home, example.com/about etc. This is much prettier than having a file extension in the url.

More information about codeigniter URLs can be found here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html