# How to include PHP script in HTML file with WampServer?

Tags: php, html, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I have an HTML script ("index.html") which includes the follow PHP code:

```
< ?php
include ('footer.php');
?>
```

The PHP script ("footer.php") contains the following code:

```
<?php
   echo "Hello world!";
?>
```

When I run :index.html: on the WampServer as a localhost, the PHP code from "index.html: is displayed. How do I display "Hello world!" from "footer.php"?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wamp Server isn't executing php code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600564/wamp-server-isnt-executing-php-code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i render .php URL with .html extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309490/how-do-i-render-php-url-with-html-extension)

Comment: A file is only passed to the PHP coliler if it ends with an extension of `.php` a file with the `.html` extension will not (by default) get passed through the PHP compiler

Comment: Also make sure you run the script from a browser and not by double clicking the file name from Explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supposed that you save php file that you want to include as footer.php in the same directory where index.php exists.
Now where you want to include footer.php, include this code at the desired location.

```
<?php
    include ('footer.php');
?>
```

I think that space between *<* and *?* in index.php was creating problem.

Edit :
Exactly space between *<* and *?* in index.php is creating problem and printing php code.

Answer (score 2):

> I have an HTML script ("index.html") which includes the follow PHP code:

This is wrong. Your `index.html` will not understand PHP Code. Rename your html code `index.html` to `index.php`.

Hope this will help

Comment: I renamed my html code index.php, and it is still printing the php code rather than "Hello world!".

Answer (score 1):

To include other php scripts your index page should be with php extension (index.php) instead of index.html

Answer (score 0):

Left click on the Wamp icon in the bottom right tray of your computer >> Apache >> left click on httpd.conf >> scroll 2/3rd's the way down >> add **AddType application/x-httpd-php .html** to  as shown below >> save and close it >> restart Wamp >> Done!

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</IfModule>
```